# I do not know how I should use "think different". How is it different from "think differently"?

Tags: difference

I think that "differently" is adverb and "different" is adjective, so I cannot say "think different". But some people use it.  How are they different? They have different meanings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Think different" is an advertising slogan that was used from 1997 to 2002 by Apple. The grammar has naturally been debated. So many advertising slogans, such as McDonald's "I'm loving it" seem to break 'rules' of grammar.

However, with this example it seems there is no rule broken, as "different" *is* considered an adverb - look at this entry in [Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/different?show=1&t=1283813816) which lists it as such, and defines it as meaning "differently".

Comment: Significantly, the "Think different" slogan was a response to IBM's slogan of "Think". It was intentionally putting focus on difference, rather than just a method of thinking.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7epnfcHy5SA) is highly relevant.